# Destructor of List cannot delete the last node

Tags: c++, list, nodes, destructor

Here is my test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class List
{
    private:
        class Node{
            public:
                int data;
                Node* next;
            public:
                virtual ~Node()
                {
                    if (next != NULL)
                    {
                        cout << "Node is out: " << data << endl;
                        delete next;
                    }
                }
                Node()
                {
                    next = NULL;
                }
        };

        Node* head;
    public:
        virtual ~List()
        {
            if (head != NULL)
            {
                delete head;
            }
        }
        List()
        {
            head = NULL;
        }
    public:
        void AddNode(int data);
        void DeleteNode(int data);
        //....  
};

void List::AddNode(int data)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp -> data = data;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* ptr = head;
        while (ptr -> next != NULL)
        {
            ptr = ptr -> next;
        }
        ptr -> next = temp;
    }   

}

int main()
{
    List test_list;
    test_list.AddNode(1);
    test_list.AddNode(2);
    test_list.AddNode(3);
    test_list.AddNode(4);
    test_list.AddNode(5);

    return 0;   
}
```

The output is like this:

```
Node is out: 1
Node is out: 2
Node is out: 3
Node is out: 4
```

It a common list and you can pay attention to the two destructor function for Node and List. I thought this one can work but the out showed that the last node cannot be deleted. I also test for other number of nodes. The result is the same, last node cannot be deleted. Thanks ahead for your advices:-).

Comment: I wouldn't write a destructor for Node. Let the List handle destroying Nodes.  It also doesn't make sense for Node to have virtual functions.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Why not have a destructor for Node? I think this a good idea. Especially when I implement a tree, I can only delete the root and all nodes will delete their children.

Comment: for a singly linked list, having the node delete the next one is overkill and an easy way to get yourself in trouble later on if you expand on this list. The List class knows exactly how the nodes are layed out -- it just takes a simple loop.

Comment: If Node had no destructor, again, let the List just traverse the list of nodes: `virtual ~List(){ Node* pHead = head; while (pHead) { Node* temp = pHead; delete pHead; pHead = temp->next; } head = NULL; }` In addition, what if I want to remove a single node? How will your destructor figure out that the "next" is *not* to be deleted if you delete the current node?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, you are right. In this case it is very inconvenient to delete a specific node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your destructor to print on the outside of the `if` statement.

The destructor **is** being called, however, on your last node `next` is `NULL`, so the `if` statement returns `false` and the cout line is not being called.

```
virtual ~Node()
{
    cout << "Node is out: " << data << endl;                
    if (next != NULL)
    {        
        delete next;
    }
}
```